# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) internal storage

Tags: java, android, java-io

I have a little bit of trouble finding my error in my Android application.

The target of my "ResultActivity" is, to create a file in the internal storage and then download a file from my server (via FTP) and then call the next Activity (GiftActivity).

But when the next Activity tries to access these files, I get the mentioned error. As far nothing new, but the interesting part is, that if I kill the application by hand and restart it, it works like a charm the next time.

Here's my code:

**ResultActivity.java:**

```
//...
ImageButton download = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.downloadCode);
download.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
assert download != null;
download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
  Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    new AsyncTask < Integer, Void, Void > () {@
      Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Integer...params) {
        try {
          JSch jsch2 = new JSch();

          session = jsch2.getSession("xy", "1.2.3.4", 22);
          session.setPassword("xyz123");
          //Set FTP Settings
          java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
          config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          //Disables Fingerprint checking!
          session.setConfig(config);
          //load config to session

          session.connect();

          //connect to the session
          channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
          channel.connect();
          //open an SFTP Channel
          channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

          File checkExistance = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("code.txt");
          if (checkExistance.exists()) {
            getBaseContext().deleteFile("code.txt");
            getBaseContext().deleteFile("usage.txt");
          }

          File code = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "code.txt");
          File usage = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "usage.txt");

          code.createNewFile();
          usage.createNewFile();

          channelSftp.get("/home/code.txt", getFilesDir() + "/code.txt");
          channelSftp.get("/home/usage.txt", getFilesDir() + "/usage.txt");
        } catch (JSchException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SftpException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
      }
    }.execute(1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ResultActivity.this, GiftActivity.class);
    ResultActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    ResultActivity.this.finish();
  }
});
```

**GiftActivity.java:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gift);

        TextView actualCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actualCode);
        TextView actualUsage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usageCode);
        String code = "";
        String usage = "";

        try {

            FileInputStream fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput("code.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            code = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            code="error1";
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput("usage.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            usage = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        usage="error2";
        }
        actualCode.setText(code);
        actualUsage.setText("you got a gift for " + usage + " congratulation!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing:

```
File code = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "code.txt");
File usage = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "usage.txt");

code.createNewFile();
usage.createNewFile();
```

With:

```
File code = new File(getBaseContext().getFilesDir(), "code.txt");
File usage = new File(getBaseContext().getFilesDir(), "usage.txt");
```